# Django POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_member/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: django

i try to add usernames to my video chatting app and this error occured. I try to fetch create_member but this error occured. I try to solve many times but failed. Kindly Check it.
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token. This error occured in console and i can't get my video and audio tracks.

```
Internal Server Error: /create_member/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 
89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: videoApp_roommember.name

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\ChattingApp\VideoChatting\videoApp\views.py", line 76, in createMember
    member, created = RoomMember.objects.get_or_create(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 
85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 657, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 492, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 302, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", 
line 1361, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 
103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 
67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 
80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 
84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 
89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: videoApp_roommember.name
[11/Oct/2022 07:47:37] "POST /create_member/ HTTP/1.1" 500 141222
```

So, here is my views.py file:

```
@csrf_exempt
def createMember(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    member, created = RoomMember.objects.get_or_create(
        name=data['name'],
        uid=data['UID'],
        room_name=data['room_name']
    )

    return JsonResponse({'name':data['name']}, safe=False)
```

here is my script.js file

```
let createMember = async () => {
    let response = await fetch('/create_member/', {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'name':NAME, 'room_name':CHANNEL, 'UID':UID})
    })
    let member = await response.json()
    return member
}
```

And here is models.py file

```
class RoomMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    insession = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after updating your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django's docs under [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/) it says:

> Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema.

So the error says

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: videoApp_roommember.name
```

Which means the changes you made, which is adding name to the model, has not been migrated to take effect on the database table so whenever you make a query or try to create a room member the error above will be thrown because of not finding the `name` column in the DB.

So you need to:

1. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` to create the migrations file for the changes you made.
2. Run `python manage.py migrate` to make the updates to the database

Comment: Happy to be of help @ShahvaizAhmed